# oracle database how to combine the two statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to combine the following two statements:

```
select password from sys.user$ where name='SYSMAN';
alter user SYSMAN identified by values '7A0F2B316C212D32';
```

Of course, '7A0F2B316C212D32' is the result obtained from the first statement. In general, given a string like 'SYSMAN', how to achieve the two statements in one stroke?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't allow this:

```
ALTER USER SYSMAN IDENTIFIED BY VALUES (SELECT password FROM sys.user$ WHERE name='SYSMAN')
```

so your only choice would seem to be PL/SQL. You can probably put that in a procedure, then call it (I assume with parameters for source & destination users).

Here is how to do it in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE move_password (
 source_user IN varchar2,
 dest_user IN varchar2
)
IS
  pass varchar(30);
BEGIN
  select password into pass from sys.user$ where name=source_user;
  execute immediate 'alter user '||dest_user||' identified by values ''' || pass || '''';
END;
```

Though, when I test it out, moving password between users like this doesn't actually work. At least in 10g. Haven't tested 11. Apparently, in 10g, the password hash includes the user name (11 is different, it may work). There is some [third-party documentation of the password algorithm](http://www.red-database-security.com/whitepaper/oracle_passwords.html).

Of course, since this includes dyamic SQL, you have to be wary of quoting—that isn't handled in the above. Assumably only sysdba will be allowed to call this procedure, so...

Comment: thanks for the info. Do you mind providing the PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: @QiangLi: I've updated my answer with a stored procedure to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is SQL generating SQL.

Something like this should give you the idea:

```
select 'alter user '||name||' identified by values '||chr(39)||password||chr(39)||';' from sys.user$ where name = 'SYSMAN';
```

That will generate the alter user statement you require:

```
alter user SYSMAN identified by values '7A0F2B316C212D32';
```

Depending on how fancy you want to get, and if you need to generate a lot of statements like that, you can spool output to a file, and then have your script call the generated script, etc.  There are lots of options.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh great. But is there a direct way of executing the generated sql other than writing to a file and then executing?

Comment: @QiangLi: You could use inline PL/SQL, by wrapping it in a `begin`/`end` block and using `execute immediate`. But of course, that's more or less what I did...